# How to Properly Share Tynker-Developed Websites with Friends Outside the Platform?

Tags: hyperlink, development-environment, embedding, sharing

There is an option to share a website I developed on tynker with friends?

I am unable to share the site I developed in Tynker, I am able to copy through the embed
the link and open it on my computer, but when I send it to my friends, they end up on Tynker's website